# Microsoft SQL Server "NOT query" not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

In all my years of coding I am perplexed. I jun ran a query through PHP on a SQL Server database and one result is missing. We will call the missing record, "Joe"

When I run:

```
SELECT [SlpName], [Memo] 
FROM OSLP 
WHERE [Memo] = 'GONE'
```

I get 8 results

```
SELECT [SlpName], [Memo] 
FROM OSLP 
WHERE [Memo] != 'GONE'
```

I get 11 results

```
SELECT [SlpName], [Memo] 
FROM OSLP
```

I get 20 results???

"Joes" record pulls up in the last query, but not in the first tWo. How can that even be possible?

One other note, when I run the query:

```
SELECT [SlpName], [Memo] 
FROM OSLP 
WHERE [SlpCode] > '0'
```

I get 20 results???

I also tried running the same queries with `SELECT * FROM` and get the same result.

Is it possible that my database is corrupted?

Comment: You probably have `NULL` values for the `Memo` field.  Those won't show up with an equality.  `NULL` is not equal to anything - not even to `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [SlpName], [Memo] FROM OSLP WHERE [Memo] IS NOT NULL
```

That should give you 19 results.

It looks like you have one row with a `NULL` Memo value.  Null is neither equal to anything, nor is it not equal to anything.  That's why your `WHERE` clause is not affecting that particular row.

Comment: You are correct, I am more used to MySQL, in MySQL, it would do one or the other, whether it was null or not.